# Application.Current.MainWindow.Close vs Application.Current.Shutdown

Tags: wpf

Should `Application.Current.Shutdown()` NOT be used as a best practice to close a WPF application?

I have a small, multiple window application and the "shutdown" seems to work nicely for all my exit commands. However, I have been told to always use `Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MainWindow.Close` won't even do anything if the [`ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) is not set respectively. You can do what you want, it should just fit what one *expects*.

(`Shutdown` will ignore the fact that some `Closing` event was cancelled, so that would be one thing you need to take into consideration)

[Also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx):

> Shutdown is implicitly called by Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) in the following situations:
>
> - When ShutdownMode is set to OnLastWindowClose.
> - When the ShutdownMode is set to OnMainWindowClose.
> - When a user ends a session and the SessionEnding event is either unhandled, or handled without cancellation.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the `ShutdownMode`. I can't remember what I was doing, but I had one WPF application where I had to set the `ShutdownMode` to `OnExplicitShutdown` due to some problems exiting the application.

Comment: @Rachel: That sounds odd, as that is the mode where it is "the least likely" to exit so to speak as you need to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks,  the canceling of the closing is a key factor for me.

Comment: I can't remember the exact details, but it had something to do with resources not being released correctly when I relied on the application to exit when the windows all got exited.