# Restarting WPF C# don't kill previous process

Tags: c#, wpf, restart

I'm developing an application using WPF on C#, and in some occasions i need to restart the application, the problem occurs when i restart the application but the old process continues to run ( i can see this on task manager). How can i restart the application killing the current process. Below my code:

**function Restart**

```
private void restart()
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method terminates this process and returns an exit code to the operating system.

```
Environment.Exit(0)
```

You can set exit code parameter to indicate whether the application is closed with an error([msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow?.Close();`

Comment: @kevintjuh93  MainWindow.Close won't even do anything if the ShutdownMode is not set respectively. You can do what you want, it should just fit what one expects. see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505619/application-current-mainwindow-close-vs-application-current-shutdown