# How to close MainWindow with closing event

Tags: c#, wpf

There are 2 windows in my application, one is log-in and the other one opens when you get authorized.

This is the function that gets called when a user logs in:

```
private void OpenWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 objWindow1 = new Window1();
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            objWindow1.Show();
        }
```

It hides the main window and opens the new one. But when I close the newly open window, the process doesn't get terminated. The application won't close.

I figured I need to access closing event, so I added this to 2nd window:

```
void DataWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
            MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();
            objMainWindow.Close();
        }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You've just created a new MainWindow and closed it again. You need to close the original

Comment: Your application doesn't close because your first window is still active (albeit invisible). Instead of hiding it, why don't you just close it?

Comment: @germi Doesn't closing the MainWindow close the whole application ? Even if some other windows have been instanciated and exists ?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: @PhilippeB. as far as I can tell from the fragments in the question, OP is not closing the main window but rather instantiating a new one which is then closed.

Comment: Oh, let me try that. I guess "new MainWindow" is creating a new one.

Comment: I'm kind of a beginner :D Can't figure out how to save MainWindow.xaml in Windo1 code in a variable exactly :D

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()` or `Application.Current.Shutdown()`. See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9505619/1136211

Comment: @germi I know that, I mean, if you close the MainWindow (the main thread), the one that you start at the begining of your program, I think it does close all the others, but that was just a question not really relevant to the post.

Comment: There is no main window concept. Thread is alive as long as there is some job to do. You can close/open as many windows as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this piece of code to the 2nd window:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
```